# How to update record after using findnext method in Ms Access

Tags: ms-access

I have created a form where 1 customer can be stored multiple times in the database I have also created a 'Find Next' button which is working perfectly but when I make changes in the form and click on the update button the data is updated on the customer which is found first in the database and not the one that I want to update. below is the code to Update button.

`Private Sub Command106_Click()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim pn As Long
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Application", dbOpenDynaset)
    pn = Me.Text85.Value
    rs.FindFirst "[Cus_Number] = " & pn
    rs.Edit
    rs.Fields("Dec_level1").Value = Me.Dec_level1
    rs.Fields("Dec_level2").Value = Me.Dec_level2
    rs.Fields("Dec_level3").Value = Me.Dec_level3
    rs.Fields("Date1").Value = Me.Date1
    rs.Fields("Date2").Value = Me.Date2
    rs.Fields("Date3").Value = Me.Date3
    rs.Fields("Com_level1").Value = Me.Com_level1
    rs.Fields("Com_level2").Value = Me.Com_level2
    rs.Fields("Com_level3").Value = Me.Com_level3
    rs.Update
    Me.App_level1 = Null
    Me.Dec_level1 = Null
    Me.Com_level1 = Null
    Me.App_level2 = Null
    Me.Dec_level2 = Null
    Me.Com_level2 = Null
    Me.App_level3 = Null
    Me.Dec_level3 = Null
    Me.Com_level3 = Null
    Me.Date1 = Null
    Me.Date2 = Null
    Me.Date3 = Null
    Me.Text85 = Null
End Sub`

Comment: How do you uniquely identify one instance of a customer over another?  Also, why don't you just code the SQL to bring up the customer itself instead of doing a FindFirst?  You're retrieving many more records than you have to and performing the extra find method for no reason, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

`FindFirst` method always find the first matching record from the available records even if duplicate records are present in the database.

you are searching using `Cus_Number` field, is this the unique/primary field or can have duplicate records??

if having duplicate records then try searching with a record which is unique/primary in the database.